# אמת at the end of קריאת שמע when not saying the brachot

Tags: shema, language, bircas-krias-shema

When saying *k'riat sh'ma al hamitah*, many (all?) people say the word *emet* at the end of the third paragraph.  Also, I believe that the common practice when saying *keriat sh'ma* without the *brachot* (for example, saying it to oneself if the *tzibur* will not reach it on time) is to say it with the word *emet* at the end of the third paragraph.

But the word *emet* is really "borrowed" from the beginning of the first *bracha* after *k'riat sh'ma*. So why do we say the word when saying *sh'ma* without the *brachot*?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we add אמת to mimic the פסוק that says וה' אֱ-לֹקים אֱמֶת from  ירמיהו פרק י:ט as mentioned in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ט"ז:ה.

Secondly we add אמת in order to have exactly 248 words once the ש"ץ has repeated ה' אֱ-לֹקיכֶם אֱמֶת. Since an individual may not repeat these words, he prefaces שמע with אֵ-ל מֶלֶךְ נֶאֱמָן - as the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch says in י"ז:ח.

So we have 2 good reasons why individuals add on אמת when saying שמע without the Brachot.

Comment: according to the talmud the verse you quoted is supposed to teach you not to interrupt between Hashem Elokechem and the beracha Emet V'yatziv... But it doesn't mention a reason for saying Emet by itself without Emet V'yatziv?

Comment: @ray - maybe, but the Kitzur understands it (to almost mean) the way I wrote it; I'm simply quoting him, almost verbatim.

Comment: i think the op was asking for the reason in light of the talmud not the straight halacha but your second point does seem to answer.